# Why getting Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in jest test for post call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I need some help with jest test. I am getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in my test

**signIn function in Action Creators makes a POST call**

```
import {SIGNING_IN, SIGNED_IN, SIGNING_FAILED, SIGNED_OUT} from "../actionTypes";
import {makePostCall} from "../../api/apiCalls";

export function signIn(data){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: SIGNING_IN});
        makePostCall('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/signin', data)
            .then(response => {
                const auth = {token: response.token, userId: response.id};
                localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(auth));
                dispatch({type: SIGNED_IN, message: 'You signed in successfully.'});
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error: ', error);
                dispatch({type: SIGNING_FAILED, message: 'Email or Password incorrect. Please try again!'});
            });

    }
}
```

**this is POST call function which gets called in above call**

```
export function makePostCall(url, data){
    return axios({method: 'post', url, data})
        .then(response => response.data)
}
```

**Test for signIn Method**

```
jest.mock('../../../src/api/apiCalls');

describe('authenticationActionCreators', () => {
    describe('signIn', () => {

        let dispatch;
        beforeEach(() => {
            jest.clearAllMocks();
            const authResponse = getAuthResponse();
            makePostCall.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(authResponse));
            dispatch = jest.fn();
        });

        test('should make post call with correct URL and data', () => {
            const data = {email: 'user@user.com', password: 'password'};
            return signIn(data)(dispatch).then(() => {
                expect(makePostCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/signin', {
                    email: 'user@user.com',
                    password: 'password'
                })
            })
        });

    });
```

Whenever i run test i get error on line `return signIn(data)(dispatch).then(() => {`

Comment: `signIn(...)(...)` does not return anything. You forgot `return` before `makePostCall('http://...', data)`.

Comment: @str you mean?

signIn(data)(dispatch).then(() => {
                return expect(makePostCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/signin', {
                    email: 'user@user.com',
                    password: 'password'
                })
            })

it still gives same error.

Comment: No. I mean you should add `return` directly in front of `makePostCall('http://...', data)` (i.e. `return makePostCall('http://...', data)`).

Answer (score -1):

i was doing it wrong. I changed it and it works

```
test('should make post call with correct URL and data', () => {
            const data = {email: 'user@user.com', password: 'password'};
            signIn(data)(dispatch);
            expect(makePostCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/signin', {
                email: 'user@user.com',
                password: 'password'
            })
        });
```